# After installing NVIDIA driver, X isn't showing

Tags: nvidia, xorg

I recently installed the NVIDIA `319` driver from the Jockey window, and now X won't load! I'm stuck with a blinking cursor. I used to have the `304` drivers installed.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happened is actually pretty common. You most likely did not uninstall the old driver.

You need to go and boot into recovery mode. Steps are below.

1. Reboot your PC.
2. After your PC's logo shows, press and hold your SHIFT key.
3. Select and boot into your newest recovery mode.
4. Open a root terminal (no networking needed).
5. Run `mount -o remount,rw /` ***DO NOT FORGET THE `remount`!***
6. Run `sudo apt-get remove nvidia-304 nvidia-settings-304`
7. reboot and log in to Ubuntu as you always have.

Bonus Step:
Fix Plymouth (the Ubuntu boot logo) by following [this tutorial from WebUpd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/03/how-to-get-plymouth-working-with-nvidia.html).